# Strange Output while using the iterating variable of a "for" loop in C

Tags: c

I'm currently developing a simple naval battle game for my first exam at my college but i'm getting a strange output on my gameboard...

[image: GameBoard]

It should be iterating my "j" variable, but instead I get that strange character...

Here's my code:

```
//CREATES COORDENATES OF THE GAMEBOARD
    //ATTRIBUTE ONE LETTER TO EACH TRAY LINE
        for (i=0;i<11;i++){
            tabuleiro[i][0] = letra[i-1];
        }
    //ATTRIBUTE ONE NUMBER TO EACH TRAY COLUMN
        for (j=1;j<11;j++){
            tabuleiro[0][j] = j;
        }

    //CREATES THE "SEA"
        for (i=1;i<11;i++){
            for (j=1;j<11;j++){
                tabuleiro[i][j] = '~';
            }
        }
```

I've tryied to change my `tabuleiro[0][j] = j;` to `tabuleiro[0][j] = (j+'0');` but then it only iterates until 9 and give me strange characters again...

[image: GameBoard_2]

If I'm not wrong I think this has something to do with the ASCII code (please correct me if I'm wrong) but I've no clue how to fix this.

Could you explain me how can I solve this please.

Comment: You need to post a [mcve].

Comment: You write: _"I've tryied to change my tabuleiro[0][j] = j; to tabuleiro[0][j] = (j+'0'); but then it only iterates until 9 and give me strange characters again..."_ is `:` the "strange" character you're mentioning? What do you expect instead of the "strange character" ?

Comment: Need more info, but `tabuleiro[i][0] = letra[i-1];` when `i == 0`, you'll get a negative index. Probably not what you want.

Comment: Please do not post text as graphics. As it's a text based game you could very well have pasted the stuff as text.

Comment: what single character do you want at the top of the 10th column?

Comment: yes @MichaelWalz the " : " is the strange character I was expeting the value of "j" in that case would be 10

Comment: @JohnnyMopp that part is working just fine, it is iterating a array of letters. I just copied all the code that creates the board and not the rest, my bad. My problem is on the second block of code... the numbers part

Comment: @pm100 I was expeting to be 10... I know it's not a single character but if I use " " instead of ' ' the results are even worst.

Comment: It was suppose to look close to this: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/65/Battleship_game_board.svg/1200px-Battleship_game_board.svg.png

Comment: "I was expecting to be 10 ... I know it's not a single character": but your table only stores a single character per element. So that was kind of overly optimistic. Using `".."` *should* work (at the correct places!), but that is more work than 'just' pasting it in here and there. You must change your entire array to a string array, and use a different way to store the digits.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

to have precise control of the character i suggest

```
tabuleiro[0][j] = "123456789T"[j];
```

This will pick the jth character from that string

BTW the reason you got ':' is becasue ':' is the next ascii character after '9' - see http://www.asciitable.com/

Comment: Excellent suggestion to use a character array (which I presume is what the `letra` array is, too). Character arithmetic is a sketchy thing.  Might want to make it "123456789D", though, for "dez".   However, the ":" is probably not because of ASCII. More generally, it _is_ because of the execution character set that the compiler was told to use or defaults to (maybe UTF-8) and the encoding of the terminal (maybe CP860). Technically, they should match but the program user could get by if they match at the characters that the program uses.

Comment: no - its because ':' is the next char after 9, nothing mysterious here

Answer (score 3):

The issue is the char code for `10 + '0' = 58` which is the char code for ':'. You might consider removing the column and row names out of the game array. They are just labels and not part of the game (I assume).

```
#define board_size 10
```

And

```
// Create game board and initialize grid to '~', in main() possibly
// Game is 10x10 grid
char tabuleiro[board_size][board_size];
for (int row = 0; row < board_size; row++) {
    for (int col = 0; col < board_size; col++) {
        tabuleiro[row][col] = '~';
    }
}
```

Have a function that draws the game board:

```
void drawBoard(char tabuleiro[board_size][board_size]) {
    // Print top line
    printf("  ");
    for (int col = 0; col < board_size; col++) {
        printf(" %-2d", col+1);
    }
    printf("\n");

    // Print grid
    for (int row = 0; row < board_size; row++) {
        // Print letter
        printf("%c ", 'A' + row);
        // Print board
        for (int col = 0; col < board_size; col++) {
            printf(" %c ", tabuleiro[row][col]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: So I can't just say tabuleiro[1][1] = "~" and when I write printf("%c",tabuleiro[1][1]) it prints me the "~" character back? because if I do this... it prints me "5"

Comment: `char`s go in single quotes. Double quotes are for strings.